# Creating a failover cluster of 2 VMs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, failover, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

I'm trying to create a cluster of 2 VMs on hyper v.  The 2 VMs and the host server all running on win 2008 r2.
When attempting to test validation for the failover cluster I'm getting an error of "disk bus type is not supported for cluster".
The problem is Hyperv can only attach vhds to SCSI or ATA, so I'm not sure on how to solve this.
**just to make it clear:**
I want the 2 VMs to be nodes in the cluster, not to be confused with a hyper v cluster on the host.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HyperV 2008 R2 you need to use an iSCSI disk as your shared storage.  This is configured in the guests same as you would a physical machine, not in Hyper-V.

Hyper-V on Server 2012 allows you to use a shared 
vhdx instead.  If you don't already have iSCSI storage available you might want to look at upgrading to get that new feature.

Answer (score 1):

2008R2 doesn't support shared VHD's.

Some alternatives:

- Use a share witness instead.
- Install Microsoft iSCSI Target on the host and connect a VHD to that. Then use the iSCSI Initiator inside the VM to connect to the iSCSI Target.